# why is Kuberenetes kubeadm init command unable to pull the images from the repository k8s.gcr.io

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I have 2 vms that run a kubernetes master and a slave node that i have setup locally. Till now everything was working fine but suddenly it started giving errors when I try to start the master with kubeadm init command.I have cpppied the error below.

```
shayeeb@ubuntu:~$ sudo kubeadm init
[init] using Kubernetes version: v1.11.1
[preflight] running pre-flight checks
I0718 11:04:57.038464   20370 kernel_validator.go:81] Validating kernel version
I0718 11:04:57.038896   20370 kernel_validator.go:96] Validating kernel config
[preflight/images] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
[preflight/images] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
[preflight/images] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
[preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
[ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image [k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver-amd64:v1.11.1]: exit status 1
[ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image [k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager-amd64:v1.11.1]: exit status 1
[ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image [k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler-amd64:v1.11.1]: exit status 1
[ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image [k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy-amd64:v1.11.1]: exit status 1
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
```

Comment: I have the same issue, just 15minutes ago.

Comment: tried, docker pull k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1 and its working and for k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver-amd64:v1.11.1 it says authetication required, I this the prob is with some particular images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also run following command rather than writing the yaml,

```
kubeadm init --kubernetes-version=1.11.0 --apiserver-advertise-address=<public_ip> --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=<private_ip>
```

If you are using flannel network run following commad,

```
kubeadm init --kubernetes-version=1.11.0 --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address=<public_ip> --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=<internal_ip>
```

Answer (score 3):

The latest version(v1.11.1) is not pulling. You can try specifying the version like

`kubeadm config images pull --kubernetes-version=v1.11.0`

Answer (score 2):

The image seems to have been removed :

https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/google-containers/GLOBAL/kube-apiserver-arm64?gcrImageListsize=50&gcrImageListquery=%255B%257B_22k_22_3A_22_22_2C_22t_22_3A10_2C_22v_22_3A_22_5C_22v1.11_5C_22_22%257D%255D

As a workaround, pull the latest available images and ignore pre flight errors

```
kubeadm config images pull --kubernetes-version=v1.11.0
kubeadm init [args] --ignore-preflight-errors=all
```

Comment: I tried to switch to pull v1.11.0 images and succeeded. But after initializing it is getting stuck in pulling control plane images.

Comment: You can modify the yaml files in the failed output and update the image files to use the version mentioned above. Then run the init command again

Answer (score 2):

I was getting similar error . Proxy was causing "kubeadm config images pull" to timeout.

Similar issue was mentioned in  https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/324
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/182#issuecomment-1137419094

And the below solution provided in the above  worked for me

systemctl set-environment HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com

systemctl set-environment HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com

systemctl restart containerd.service

Comment: Hours wasted! Thanks for this. Not sure why I never thought about systemctl envs.

Comment: Tried so many things, finally this worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach as it is working:

You can create config.yaml file, for example

```
cat config.yaml
    apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha1
    kind: MasterConfiguration
    api:
      advertiseAddress: 10.44.70.201
    networking:
      podSubnet: 192.168.0.0/16
    kubernetesVersion: 1.11.0
```

and run kubeadm init --config=kubeadm-config.yaml